# IDEA 2021.1 - How to to run gradle tasks with project directory as current working directory?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Edit: Note this issue is supposedly fixed in IDEA 2021.1.1.

So it seems Jetbrains have changed how the Gradle integration works in the latest 2021.1 version of IDEA.

Gradle tasks might no longer execute with the project directory as the current working directory, as per: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265203

Does anyone know of a quick workaround for this issue so that I can get a Gradle build working in IDEA **without changing the Gradle script**?

Current workaround: downgrade to IDEA 2020.3 where Gradle scripts continue to work as they did previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be fixed with 2021.1.1
See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265797